# How many permutations $f$ of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ satisfy $f(1) < f(2)$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many permutations $f$ of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ satisfy $f(1) < f(2)$ ?

I think I am struggling to fully grasp exactly what I am solving. Am I looking to see the number of permutations where 1 is mapped to a value that is less than what 2 is mapped to?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Hint: there is no special relationship between $1$ and $2$ in this context.

Comment: Very symmetric indeed.

Comment: This is a standard exercise with standard language.  You are wanting to count the permutations **12**3456, **12**3465, ... **35**1246, **35**1264, ... **56**4321 where in every permutation the first digit is smaller than the second digit.

Comment: As for actually counting this, there are a number of approaches.  The first and easiest which has already been alluded to is to appeal to symmetry, that one would expect the first digit to be smaller than the second digit just as often as one would have the first digit be larger than the second digit.  That can be formalized with a bijective argument, showing a bijection between the set of permutations whose first digit is smaller than second and the set of permutations whose first digit is larger than the second.

Comment: The longer way, but might be more comfortable to a beginning student, is to actually count these with a multiplication argument... First pick the two digits that appear in the first and second slots simultaneously and recognize that there is only one way to place them such that the first is smaller than the second.  Then, approach with rule of product as usual to fill in the remaining positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\binom{6}{2}$ is the number of cases choosing two of the numbers, and first one is the smaller second one is the bigger number.

$4!$ is the number of arrangements of remaining 4 numbers

$\binom{6}{2}4!$

Alternatively

Total number of arrangements is $6!$

and in half of them first one is smaller then the second one that is $\dfrac{6!}{2}$

Comment: Correct, though it is worth pointing out that $\binom{6}{2}4! = \frac{6!}{2}$ to make the connection between the results of the mentioned approaches more obvious.